# Wordpress : How to setup User Roles for Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, user-roles

I'm working on a system for company using WordPress. To go about this I'm making a new custom post type `EMPLOYEE` and I need 2 corresponding users `AGENT` and `CUSTOMER` for it:

`The`AGENT`user can create and edit his own`EMPLOYEE(s)`, but not edit the EMPLOYEE(s)` of other `AGENT(s)`.

The `EMPLOYEE` post can be viewed and commented on by all `AGENTs, CUSTOMERs` and the general public,
which also implies that the `CUSTOMER` user can only view all `EMPLOYEE` posts.
The `CUSTOMER` user needs to be differentiated from the general public because once they hire an `EMPLOYEE`, the system needs to associate them with the `EMPLOYEE`, thus the need for the `CUSTOMER` to be a signed-in user.

Finally, both `AGENT` and `CUSTOMER` users can create/edit their own vanilla WordPress user profiles and sign-in with their username/password combination.

How do I execute this arrangement? The online documentation on users and capabilities had me pulling my hair and running around in circles. So far here's my custom post type registration, and I'm currently setting up the meta boxes for other info for this post type:

```
/*** Register Custom Post Type " Company " ***/
function out_clients() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'AGENT', 'Post Type General Name' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'AGENT', 'Post Type Singular Name' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'AGENT'  ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'AGENT' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'ALL AGENT' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'VIEW'  ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'ADD'  ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'ADD'  ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'EDIT'  ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'EDIT'  ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'SEARCH'  ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'NOT FOUND'  ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'NO IN TRASH'  ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array(  'title' ),
    'taxonomies'          => array(),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/cli_icon.png',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'out_clients', $args );
}
/*** Hook into the 'init' action **/
add_action( 'init', 'out_clients', 0 );
```

and my role :-

```
$result = add_role(
    'visitor',
    __( 'visitor' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
    )
);
```

Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After many an attempt at getting this working I settled for a role based plugin. That allowed me to add new roles and restrict certain pages to a role or group - that might be a better bet.

Comment: ok bu what user role you add for visitor ??

Comment: @ScottMcGready Yes, The best way is use [https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/). and try this [webhostinghub](http://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/wordpress/wordpress-users-capabilities/top-five-user-roles-capabilities-plugins).

Comment: yes but its not work with costume post type

Comment: ok but when i login to my site, i cannot open this `page wp-admin/profile.php`